# C# Как импортировать C++ dll который возвращает класс Vector2

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-c++, dllimport

C# Как импортировать Dll который возвращает класс Vector2.

C++

```
namespace ExtremeEngineEditor
{

class Vector2
{
public:
    float X, Y;

    Vector2(float x, float y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
};

    extern "C" GUILAYOUT_API Vector2 GetDisplaySize();
}
```

C#

```
#if ExtremeEngineEditor

using ExtremeEngine.Math;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ExtremeEngineEditor
{

/// <summary>
/// GUILayout made to draw editor gui.
/// GUILayout works on Dear ImGui.
/// </summary>
public static class GUILayout
{

    [DllImport("ExtremeEngine")]
    public static extern Vector2 GetDisplaySize();
}
}
#endif
```

И мой Vector2 класс в С#.

```
namespace ExtremeEngine
{
namespace Math
{
    public class Vector2
    {

        public float X = 0, Y = 0;

        public Vector2()
        {

        }

        public Vector2(int x)
        {
            X = x;
        }

        public Vector2(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x; Y = y;
        }

        public static readonly Vector2 Zero = new(0, 0);

        public static readonly Vector2 One = new(1, 1);

        public static readonly Vector2 OneMinus = new(-1, -1);

        public static readonly Vector2 Left = new(-1, 0);

        public static readonly Vector2 Up = new(0, 1);

        public static readonly Vector2 Right = new(1, 0);

        public static readonly Vector2 Down = new(0, -1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2685157/12888024 класс C++ не имеет ничено общего с C#. Маршаллируйте данные, а не класс. И в C# есть готовая структура `System.Numerics.Vector2`, поддерживающая аппаратное ускорение для вычислений, не изобретайте лишнего. Не забудьте указать конвенцию вызовов при маршаллинге, в данном случае наверное `CallingConvention.Cdecl`. Хотя она используется только в x86 приложениях, то есть целевая архитектура "Any CPU" не подойдёт.